# JQuery addclass/removeclass by div ID

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass, removeclass

I want to addClass()/removeClass() for divs with different class name and I try to find them by `id`.

How I can make this work?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button_hof").click(function() {
        $("#button_hof").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button_hof" class="button_hof selected"></div>
<div id="button_hof" class="button_hof"></div>
<div id="button_hof" class="button_hof2"></div>
<div id="button_hof" class="button_hof2"></div>
```

Comment: id must be unique !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to have id's on each of the items you are watching. As the other commenter stated, the `ID` on an element must be unique.

http://jsfiddle.net/du64um5y/

```css
.selected {
    color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_hof selected">1</div>
<div class="button_hof">2</div>
<div class="button_hof">3</div>
<div class="button_hof">4</div>
```

```js
var allButtons = jQuery('.button_hof');
jQuery('.button_hof').click(function(e){
    var $active = jQuery(this);
    allButtons.removeClass('selected');
    $active.addClass('selected');
});
```